# if code returns an error do not run query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli, stripe-payments

I have the following code:

```
<?php
  require_once('./config.php');
include("includes/db.php");
  $token  = $_POST["token"];
    $userId  = $_POST["userId"];

  $email = $_POST["userEmail"];
    $courseProvider = $_POST["courseProvider"];

  $amount = $_POST["priceFinal"];
    $courseTitle = $_POST["courseTitle"];

  $amount = $amount * 100;
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => $email,
      'card'  => $token
  ));

  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => $amount,
      'currency' => 'cad'
  ));

$amountDisplay = $amount / 100;
$course_paid = "Yes";
$course_paid_date = date("Y-m-d");

$insert_c = "insert into order_complete (course_title, course_price, course_buyer, course_provider, course_paid_date) 
             values ('$courseTitle','$amount','$email','$courseProvider','$course_paid_date')";
    $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $insert_c);

    $insert_c2 = "Update orders SET course_paid = '$course_paid' where course_id = '$userId'";
    $run_c2 = mysqli_query($con, $insert_c2);


  echo "<h4>Successfully charged $$amountDisplay to $email</h4>";




?>
```

where I would only want the queries to be executed if the following runs succesfully (no errors is returned)

```
  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
          'customer' => $customer->id,
          'amount'   => $amount,
          'currency' => 'cad'
      ));
```

The reason for that is that I do not want to record in the database that the payment was successful when stripe was not able to finalize the transaction before of a error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we would need to do is to understand what that function returns:
`\Stripe\Charge::create` on success and then using a simple condition we'll compare the `$charge` value to the success values.

While I'm not truly familiar with this API, according to their [API of `create charge`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) the response for creating a new charge:

> Returns a charge object if the charge succeeded. Returns an error if
>   something goes wrong. A common source of error is an invalid or
>   expired card, or a valid card with insufficient available balance.

So you can use use `try - catch` block, as you can see in the following example: (https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges)

```
$stripChargeValid = true;
try {
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
  "currency" => "usd",
  "source" => $token,
  "description" => "Example charge")
);
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined
  $stripChargeValid = false;
}

if($stripChargeValid){
   //Run your queries.
}
```

Or in a more comprehensive way:

```
try {
  // Use Stripe's bindings...
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught
  $body = $e->getJsonBody();
  $err  = $body['error'];

  print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
  print('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
  print('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");
  // param is '' in this case
  print('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
  print('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");
} catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
  // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {
  // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
  // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
} catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
  // Network communication with Stripe failed
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
  // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
  // yourself an email
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
}
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation and examples. where for instance would i plugin my queries, to ensure that they only run on success?

Comment: **Edited my answer.** You can define a variable inside the `catch block`, for instance: `$error = true`, and after the `try-catch` block just check if this variable `isset` and its value is true: `if(isset($error) && $error) { ..... }`

Comment: Yes it works marveously well. Thanks much. One note, is that i would like to record the error message in the database. i tried putting the query in catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) { but it didnt seem to work

Comment: Start by printing it in order to check if this is the "right catch" block. If it does print the error, there's something wrong with your query.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($run_c === TRUE){
    $insert_c2 = "Update orders SET course_paid = '$course_paid' where course_id = '$userId'";
    $run_c2 = mysqli_query($con, $insert_c2);
}
```